# Bootstrap.css and Vendors.min.js are creating problem for an Autocomplete Textbox in Asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am facing a problem while making an autocomplete textbox in asp.net with javascript and c#

The problem is that nothing is working if I include the links to `/bootstrap.css` and `/vendors.min.js` on my page.aspx.

If I remove those then everything works fine.
I cannot remove that link and script because my full project is depending on them. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

These are the tags I've added:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app-assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>

<script src="/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js"></script>
```

This is my Script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#textbox").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var param = {
                name_details: $('#textbox').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "Page.aspx/Get_Names",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datafilter: function(data) {
                    return data;
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(items) {
                        return {
                            value: items
                        }
                    }))
                },
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
</script>
```

this is my c# Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> Get_Names (string name_details)
{
    String Command_Query = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SP_Product_Name_Search"].ToString();
    List<string> Product_names = new List<string>();
    String MasterConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connectionstring"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MasterConnection);
    string sqlqry = string.Format(Command_Query + " '{0}'", name_details);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlqry,con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        Product_names.Add(sdr.GetString(0));        
    }
    con.Close();
    return Product_names;
}
```

Comment: Are there any javascript errors? I just want to be clear... the above JQuery autocomplete code stops working as soon as you include your vendors bundle & bootstrap css?

Comment: What libs are in your vendors bundle & and to be explicit, does the autocomplete work as expected when vendors isn't included?

Comment: yes...
exactly...
it stops working when i include vendors bundle & bootstrap css in the page.
it works perfectly when I remove vendors and bootstrap tag from the page
and there is no javascript error.